# Problems with multiple select element with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm trying to create a  element, that should look like this http://joxi.ru/HsLHUhjKTJD6f-E_R5I. I found a [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin, but how could I make it looks like the  on the screenshot? Or I should use another plugin?

Comment: I do not have time to answer your question, if you had asked a question. We are not here to do your work for you, show us what you tried, and if you have not tried anything, then try and post your code above.

Comment: I'm not familliar with javascript, that's the problem. Maybe anyone knows how to make this plugin expanded by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want to achieve : http://www.1stwebdesigns.com/blog/development/multiple-select-with-checkboxes-and-jquery